# How to you see if the first/last item in one string in an array aligns with the first/last item in another string in the array in python?

Tags: python

Let's say I want to see if the first item in one string is the same first item as the second string in the array.  I also want to check if the last item of the first string aligns with the last item of the second string in the array.  See below of the example.

If anyone could help me with this, it would be greatly appreciated.  T

"[A2], [A8]"  would equal True because 'A' and 'A' align.
"[B7], [C7]" would equal True because the 7's align.

```py
def can_capture(rooks):
    if rooks.startswith() == rooks.startswith() or rooks.endswith() == rooks.endswith():
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

```py
def can_capture(rooks):
    if rooks[0] == rooks[2] or rooks[1] == rooks[3]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Write a function that returns True if two rooks can attack each other, and False otherwise.

Examples

```
can_capture(["A8", "E8"]) ➞ True

can_capture(["A1", "B2"]) ➞ False

can_capture(["H4", "H3"]) ➞ True

can_capture(["F5", "C8"]) ➞ False
```

Notes
Assume no blocking pieces.
Two rooks can attack each other if they share the same row (letter) or column (number).

Comment: Adding your own coding attempt would make this clearer and attract more answers

Comment: `"[A2], [A8]"` is just one string, not two strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def can_capture(rooks):
    if rooks[0][0] == rooks[1][0] or rooks[0][1] == rooks[1][1]:
        return True
    else
        return False
        
print(can_capture(["A8", "E8"]))  # True
print(can_capture(["A1", "B2"]))  # False
print(can_capture(["H4", "H3"]))  # True
print(can_capture(["F5", "C8"]))  # False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so like this IIUC:

```
def compare(str1, str2):
    return str1[0] == str2[0] or str1[-1] == str2[-1]

print(compare('A2', 'A8'))
print(compare('B7', 'C7'))
print(compare('B7', 'C9'))

# prints
True
True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

`startswith()` and `endswith()` are for testing whether a string starts or ends with a specific string. They don't return what the string starts or ends with.

Use indexing to get particular characters of a string. Index `0` is the first character, `-1` is the last character.

```
def strings_match(s1, s2):
    return s1[0] == s2[0] or s1[-1] == s2[-1]
```

`can_capture` gets a list of strings, you can extract each string before calling strings_match()`.

```
def can_capture(rooks):
    return strings_match(rooks[0], rooks[1])
```

Comment: The problem is that it only gives me ONE parameter to work with.  How do I deal with only one parameter with this???

Comment: I just added that.